# Multi-Desktop in tablet (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet, multiscreen

I'm going to do some project we need to manage 2 screen (output), one of them needs to display on tablet and another output needs to display on other monitor.

Actually  I have 2 Apps we need display one of them on tablet another on regular monitor.

I know we can do it simply in windows but I'm not sure about Android and Tablet. I will be grateful if you help me through that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know android does not support multi-desktop fardermore  your hardware needs to support multi-desktop